# Ubuntu 22.4 Installation Installs but will not start on reboot

Tags: boot

I have installed Ubuntu and have completed the installation with no problems.  I install as a brand new install over the top of Windows 10.  I get to the end of the instal and Reboot. A message to remove installation media appears.  I do so and reboot. But Ubuntu will not start.. I get a black DOS like window and no opening of UBUNTU.
On trying to reinstall after this the installation sees the new install but it will not open.  It appears that there is no Boot Manager.
I am using a 4 year old HP laptop with plenty, 16GB Ram and acres of HDD
Anyone help please?
TIA
Ken

Comment: for re-installation, you'd need to change your bios so that it boot from the flash drive. If you are still having problem after re-installation, you might want to check whether there is problem with your flash.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it)

Comment: I also have an HP laptop of similar age, based on the AMD chipset Ryzen5/Radeon. I haven't been able to get X/Ubuntu 22.04 to work. I am now using Debian. I wondered if there is a problem with the AMD firmware???

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue with Ubuntu 22.04 fresh install and dual boot with Windows 10, after **turning the secure boot off** from the bios of my PC, Ubuntu booted normally. Hopefully, this answer help the people who will face this issue.